# Discrepancy in marginal likelihood in non-stationary gaussian process

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian, maximum-likelihood, stationarity, gaussian-process

I am working on implementing a variation of the Gibbs kernel (Eq. 4.32 in [GPML book](http://www.gaussianprocess.org/gpml/chapters/RW4.pdf)) proposed by [Plagemann et al.](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-540-87481-2_14). The authors propose a method to learn latent length scales at $m$ locations ($m << n$) and then inferring length scales at all $n$ locations using the second-level GP. They also mention that we need to use combined marginal likelihood to learn the optimal hyperparameters. I understand that the following equation is the closed-form marginal likelihood,
[image]

But, for the second level GP, authors use a slightly different equation (missing the first term compared to above),
[image]

Can someone explain if there is some problem in the above equation or am I missing some very important detail?